# Laravel: Cannot access empty property when trying to send an email

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm trying to send an email using laravel however I keep getting the `cannot access empty property` error whenever I run my code.
I've done my research on the error and it seems to be usually caused by using a `$` before the property name, example `$this->$username` instead of `$this->username`. However, that isn't the case in my code.

I can't really tell what's causing it nor do I have great experience in Laravel
Here's my mailable class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class VerificationMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $data;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $data2 = ['companyName' => $this->data['name'], 'verificationCode' => $this->data['verificationCode']];
        return $this->from('noreply@REMOVED.com')
               ->$this->view('emails.verification', $data2);
    }
}
```

My view is saved in resources/views/emails/verification.blade.php
I saw also that this error can sometimes be caused by using `$message` as variable name inside the views, however that isn't the case with me. I tried loading the view with a normal route without any mail sending involved and it loaded normally.
 Can anyone spot it? Thanks.

Comment: Does the error say anything more helpful than `cannot access empty property` usually there would be some indication of the script line the error occured on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error here:

```
return $this->from('noreply@REMOVED.com')
    ->$this->view('emails.verification', $data2);
```

Use following instead: (remove second `$this->`)

```
return $this->from('noreply@REMOVED.com')
    ->view('emails.verification', $data2);
```

Comment: Knew it was gonna be something obvious, thank you. I feel stupid now.